# How is spilled fuel cleaned up at airports?

Tags: airport, fuel

In an accident where an airplane [leaks fuel onto the ground](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qantas_Flight_32), how is it cleaned up?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the quantity, jet fuel can be cleaned up by use of a sump truck and dry absorbent material or if permitted by the airport and local environmental regulations, the fire department can spray water to wash it down the storm drain.

Comment: Both seem perfectly reasonable. However, they would seem much more legitimate if you had some regulation and/or legal references.